# Works that tackle the question of vegetarianism

Tags: ethics

I'm looking for recommendations of works that argue for or against vegetarianism primarily from an ethical (rather than health or religious) POV. Rather than Epicurus, Pythagoras, et al., I'm interested in "modern" views on this.

I realise that this is a little open-ended. But I'm interested in all angles (from both sides) on this: animal cruelty, plant vs. animal sentience, in vitro meat, etc.

Comment: [Peter Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Singer) writes pretty extensively about this?

Comment: Plant sentience??

Comment: @RexKerr Poor choice of phrase, perhaps. This is the argument that animals can experience pleasure, pain, & suffering and can be thought to be sentient whereas plants can not (thus implying that animals shouldn't be killed whereas plants can). Others argue that plants too can be considered "sentient" citing examples of plant communication etc. Essentially, the debate is on where to draw the ethical line on what can and cannot be killed and eaten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Peter Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Singer)'s *[Animal Liberation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Liberation_%28book%29)* is a must read. Anything by [Gary Francione](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_L._Francione) is excellent for the moral and legal aspects about animal exploitation. [Melanie Joy](http://www.carnism.org/2012-05-15-16-41-47/27-bios/37-about-dr-melanie-joy)'s book on carnism is excellent in understanding the social psychology behind meat consumption. There is also [Tom Reagan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Regan) if you want something that's very academic.

Answer (score -2):

I am not aware of a work that takes a position against vegetarianism or animal rights, but I think the idea of animal rights is untenable. To explain why I will set the issue in a broader context than people usually consider.

There are some things that have rights and others that don't. Human beings have rights, rocks don't. What explains the difference? The answer given by advocates of animal rights is that if something suffers then it should be granted rights. People then look at animals and see something that looks the way a person would look if he was suffering and say that it is suffering. Sometimes they go a bit further and talk about humans and animals having similar brain structures and say that the animal must be suffering since it has those structures in common with us.

However, animals lack the ability to create new explanatory knowledge, unlike people. Dogs never learn to write, they don't learn English beyond some short list of commands, they can't write music or program computers. The reason is that a dog has a finite bag of tricks written into its genes and when it exhausts that bag of tricks it can't create anything new. Other animals are in the same position. For example, experiments in trying to teach apes language always reach a point where the ape can't do anything more sophisticated than what it already does. See "Kanzi: The Ape at the Brink of the Human Mind" by Sue Savage-Rumbaugh and Roger Lewin for an example. I think this is relevant in two ways.

First, we have nothing to gain by granting animals rights. The animal has a particular set of knowledge (in the sense of useful or explanatory information) in its genes. So any copy of the relevant genes will have the same knowledge and no individual animal matters very much. By contrast, each person has a unique set of ideas and habits instantiated in his brain and that does matter. Every time a person dies unique ideas are destroyed that might lead to progress. Every time you mistreat a person you make it more difficult to get access to any good ideas he might have or that he might develop. So humans should have rights and animals shouldn't.

Second, the idea that animals suffer is false. An animal can't understand what is happening to it and so can't interpret the pain as being bad. The idea that something is bad is a sophisticated interpretation of experiences that only arises in the light of a lot of knowledge. For example, one reason people suffer is that they can imagine all the stuff they won't be able to do as a result of injury or death, unlike animals. Animals are robots programmed to propagate genes. To do this, genes program their vehicles to move away from stuff that will damage the vehicle, refrain from using damaged body parts so they can heal, signal danger to relatives and other stuff like that. They bear more resemblance to characters in a computer game than to people.

You might say that it looks like animals suffer, but that is an interpretation of what you see when you look at an injured animal. The explanation I have given criticises that interpretation. Likewise when you say an animal has a brain structure that is similar to some human brain structure you are imposing a false interpretation of what is going on. Both the human brain and the animal brain are universal computers: they can do anything that a universal Turing machine can do. It follows that you can't tell exactly what it is doing just by looking at the hardware. To the extent that some part of the animal's brain is similar to a person's brain it is participating in a very different process. The computation in the animal's brain doesn't involve understanding what is happening to it or anticipating problems as a result of an injury or anything like that: the animal doesn't suffer.

People should eat animals if they like meat and they shouldn't feel guilty about it.

For an extended discussion of issues related to animal rights see this email discussion:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beginning-of-infinity/khortjsNuY8/CbxfUXFAGUUJ.

Comment: `By contrast, each person has a unique set of ideas and habits instantiated in his brain and that does matter. Every time a person dies unique ideas are destroyed that might lead to progress.` Be very careful, that logic implies that brain dead person, person in vegetative state, person in permanent comatose, person with very low IQs, as ineligible for human rights.

Comment: If a person can speak he can learn, so people with low IQs are still people and still capable of creating knowledge. As for people in a coma, it may be possible to create knowledge while asleep, we don't really know since we don't understand it too well, so we should give them the benefit of the doubt whenever possible.
A person who is actually brain dead doesn't have rights. He may have rights while he is still alive to stipulate what will happen to his stuff, including his body, after he is dead.

Comment: "If a person can speak he can learn" so the dumbs, deafs, and babies aren't eligible for human right? What do we stand to gain from granting permanent comatose and [idiots](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot) with rights? Did you not just say that we should only give something rights if we stand to gain something from it?

Comment: Also, I don't think the author of the study you cited would agree with your conclusions that animal can't learn new knowledge, Sue Savage-Rumbaugh is a staunch supporter of the idea that Kanzi did learn language. [Other ape in similar language studies](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koko_(gorilla)) been documented to be capable of inventing new gestures, in other words, inventing knowledge.

Comment: It does not follow from "if a person can speak, he can learn" that only people who speak can learn. Dumbs, deafs and babies can all learn as illustrated by the fact that they learn language.
I am willing to grant people in a coma every possible benefit of the doubt.
You comment about "idiots" is bad. Some people learn somewhat less about knowledge that is common among adults than others. There is no reason to think they can't learn. Worse, all you know about an "idiot" is that you place a higher priority on learning some things than he does. Some of his choices may be better than yours.

Comment: About Kanzi, what I said was "experiments in trying to teach apes language always reach a point where the ape can't do anything more sophisticated than what it already does." Such behaviour can be explained if the animal is not creating any new knowledge. All that's happening is that you're taking advantage of some knowledge instantiated in the animal's genes that helps it adapt to particular circumstances, but not to create new explanations.

Comment: As for "inventing new gestures" I doubt that this is the correct interpretation. As I have stated, all animal language research runs into severe limitations on the kinds of signals the animal produces. This seems inconsistent with the idea that the animal is actually creating new knowledge, including new gestures. If a researcher notices that some particular movement is correlated with the animal noticing X then the researcher might say the animal has created a new sign but the animal might just be moving to get ready to do something with X, e.g. - eat it or catch it.